# How to invoke Oracle REST service using basic authentication

Tags: oracle, rest, basic-authentication

How does one invoke an Oracle REST data service, reflecting a select on a view, using basic authentication?

I've got this to work without authentication, but as soon as I turn on authentication, and add credentials to the client's call, the server returns a 404 error.

For the server, I'm using an Oracle database hosted on Oracle cloud.

```
select * from V$VERSION returns ...

BANNER                                                                           BANNER_FULL                                                                                                                                                      BANNER_LEGACY                                                                        CON_ID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production           Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production                                                                                           Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production                    0
                                                                                 Version 19.5.0.0.0
```

### What works

Given a target schema called `connect4`, and a view which has been REST-enabled, with object name `game`, the following powershell script on a client, works and returns a correct data set, when `authentication required` is turned off at the server ...

```
$url  = 'https://<redacted>.adb.ap-sydney-1.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/connect4/game'
$return = Invoke-RestMethod $url
$return | select -expandProperty Content | convertFrom-Json
```

### What doesn't works

However, when I turn  `authentication required` turn on, the following powershell script should work, but does not. Instead it returns 404. `$user` in this listing is the connect4 user account password. The credentials are passed using the Basic Authentication protocol. The password has been validated as correct.

```
$url  = 'https://<redacted>.adb.ap-sydney-1.oraclecloudapps.com/ords/connect4/game'
$user = 'connect4'
$pass = '<redacted>'
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $pass -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential( $user, $secpasswd)
$return = Invoke-RestMethod $url -Credential $credential -headers @{'X-ID-TENANT-NAME' = '<redacted>'}
$return | select -expandProperty Content | convertFrom-Json
```

### Speculation

Could it be that some kind of grant needs to be applied to the connect4 user to enable it to select it's own object via REST?
Or do I have the client call wrong?

---

### Update

The actual object surfaced by the REST services is the view `GAME_VW`. It has a REST object alias of `game`, and the REST authorization required is the ORDS role `oracle.dbtools.role.autorest.CONNECT4.GAME_VW`. I believe that an `ORDS role` is a different concept to a regular Oracle role, and so can't be granted/revoked in the usual way.

The DDL for the REST settings of the view is ...

```
DECLARE
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
    ORDS.ENABLE_OBJECT(p_enabled => TRUE,
                       p_schema => 'CONNECT4',
                       p_object => 'GAME_VW',
                       p_object_type => 'VIEW',
                       p_object_alias => 'game',
                       p_auto_rest_auth => TRUE);
    commit;
END;
```

I believe that the ORDS role for this user is correctly set up. The following query ...

```
select NAME as ROLE_NAME, sys_context( 'userenv', 'current_schema' ) as CURRENT_SCHEMA, USER
  from USER_ORDS_ROLES
 where NAME = 'oracle.dbtools.role.autorest.CONNECT4.GAME_VW';
```

... returns ...

```
ROLE_NAME                                       CURRENT_SCHEMA USER
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
oracle.dbtools.role.autorest.CONNECT4.GAME_VW   CONNECT4       CONNECT4
```

and this query, using the same session ...

```
select NAME, SCHEMA_ID
  from USER_ORDS_ROLES
 where NAME like 'oracle.dbtools.role.autorest.CONNECT4%';
```

... returns ...

```
NAME                                           SCHEMA_ID
--------------------------------------------------------
oracle.dbtools.role.autorest.CONNECT4          10011
oracle.dbtools.role.autorest.CONNECT4.GAME_VW  10011
```

The DDL for this privilege is ...

```
DECLARE
  l_roles     OWA.VC_ARR;
  l_modules   OWA.VC_ARR;
  l_patterns  OWA.VC_ARR;
BEGIN
  ORDS.ENABLE_SCHEMA(
      p_enabled             => TRUE,
      p_schema              => 'CONNECT4',
      p_url_mapping_type    => 'BASE_PATH',
      p_url_mapping_pattern => 'connect4',
      p_auto_rest_auth      => TRUE);    
  ORDS.CREATE_ROLE(p_role_name  => 'oracle.dbtools.role.autorest.CONNECT4.GAME_VW');
  l_roles(1)   := 'oracle.dbtools.autorest.any.schema';
  l_roles(2)   := 'oracle.dbtools.role.autorest.CONNECT4.GAME_VW';
  l_patterns(1):= '/game/*';
  l_patterns(2):= '/metadata-catalog/game/*';
  ORDS.DEFINE_PRIVILEGE(
      p_privilege_name => 'oracle.dbtools.autorest.privilege.CONNECT4.GAME_VW',
      p_roles          => l_roles,
      p_patterns       => l_patterns,
      p_modules        => l_modules,
      p_label          => '',
      p_description    => '',
      p_comments       => NULL);      
  COMMIT; 
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have granted an appropriate role to the user. Using the following sql run as Sysdba...

1. To see what priv the user connect4 has `SELECT name  FROM  user_ords_roles Where NAME like 'oracle.dbtools.role.autorest.%';`
2. To see the names of the existing roles `SELECT * FROM DBA_ROLE_PRIVS WHERE GRANTEE = 'CONNECT4';`
3. Finally to grant the required role: `GRANT 'oracle.dbtools.role.autorest.CONNECT4.game' TO CONNECT4;`

After the above try calling the curl again.

For further reading see:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-authentication

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not it. The issues are two-fold.
(1) As illustrated in the update, connect4 already has the aforementioned role;
(2) Corpse's mentioned grant statement (Item 3 in Corpse's answer) is would not be valid anyway, because these are ORDS roles, not Oracle roles.